# Should static member functions be avoided in shared libraries?

Tags: c++, c, static, global-variables, shared-libraries

In reading the book "Writing Scientific Software" by Oliveira and Stewart, I came across this interesting passage:

> "*Shared variables are dangerous and should be avoided in shared libraries*
>
> So if you are writing a shared or dynamically linked library, avoid `static` or `saved` local variables and avoid global variables."
>
> (page 55)

But what about `static` member functions? Are these equally as dangerous in a shared library? Should I avoid these as well? Why/why not?

Comment: The reason given by the authors is that the code won't be re-entrant; that is, it would be risky to have multiple applications run the same DLL since static/global variables would be shared.

Comment: Regarding static members/variables and sharing; one *good* use case for these in shared libraries is global event and thread ids. This can easily lead to thread-safety. Other static members are often best placed in associated header files for your library inside of classes/structs which are sensitive to their context. Meanwhile you always want to be very stringent on what you place in global space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But what about `static` member functions? Are these equally as dangerous in a shared library?

Not at all: `static` member functions should not be avoided: unlike `static` variables that represent shared state, `static` member functions represent shared computations. As long as these computations are *stateless*, they are not dangerous at all.

Comment: Variables are mutable, static member functions, like simple functions, are immutable. So whatever problem variables may have, functions don't share it.

Answer (score 3):

Static *functions* are not a problem. In fact, many of the functions one would commonly use in scientific software are pure math functions such as `sin()`, `sqrt()`, `log()`.

Static *variables*, on the other hand, are an indicator of shared state and should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Not inherently. A static member function which doesn't use any static state (e.g. ones that use only local or thread-local variables) isn't unsafe. Such methods are frequently used in well respected libraries such as boost or guava (that last example from the java world).